# Can I use the Baofeng UV-5R radio with the older model RETREVIS RT-5R? They look like the exact same unit

Tags: baofeng

Can I use the Baofeng UV-5R radio with the older model RETREVIS RT-5R?  They look like the exact same unit.

Comment: Removed the seemingly *completely* unrelated [tag:gnuradio] tag!

Comment: Hi Deon, welcome to the Ham Radio Stack Exchange (SE). You may know that SE questions are lightly curated to embrace questions that have at least some research behind them.  FYI, I’m voting to close this question because it  seems to be  unresearched and not of help to the community. I hope you don't take this as discouragement from participation, and look forward to more in the future!

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  What do you mean by "use with?"  Communicate with?  If that's what you mean, what frequency ranges do the two radios support that you have the right to communicate on?  

please clarify your question or it is in danger of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "use ... with"? If you mean "can transmissions from each radio be heard on the other", then as long as they can be set up to transmit on common frequencies, with common modulation, and so on, then yes.

In this case, it seems these are both VHF/UHF band ham radios using analog FM. So they are definitely interoperable. Depending on where you live, it is likely to be unlawful to use these radios without some kind of licensing. In the U.S. you would need to have an amateur radio license to transmit using these radios - based on their documented bands.

If you mean something different, please explain in some more details so we can give you a useful answer.